# include an external JS file into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

We have an assignment where I need to insert an external JavaScript file in a html.

**HTML File**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
 <body onload="do_game()">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/colguess.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**JS File**

```
var guess_input_color;
var finished=false;
var colors=["blue","cyan","gold","gray","green","magenta","red","white","yellow"];
var guesses=0;
function do_game(){
  var n=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  var color=colors[n];
  while(!finished){
    guess_input_color=prompt("i am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n"+colors+"\n\nWhat color am i thinking of?");
    ++guesses;
    finished=check_guess();
  }
}
function check_guess(){
  if(colors.indexOf(guess_input_color)==-1)
   {
     alert("Sorry, i don't recognize your color.\n\nPlease try again.");
     return false;
   }
  if(color>guess_input_color){
        alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint:your color is alphabetically lesser than mine\n\nPlease try again.");
         return false;
    }
   if(color<guess_input_color){
        alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint:your color is alphabetically higher than mine\n\nPlease try again.");
        return false;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = guess_input_color;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = guess_input_color;
    alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\nIt took you"+guesses+" guesses to finish the game!\n\n")
    return true;
   }
```

Note: both html and js files are in the same directory.

Comment: Change `/colguess.js` to `colguess.js`. The `/` is saying "go to the root of the server, or drive, then find this file".

Comment: Thank you @MikeC. i got it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IT should be  this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="colguess.js"></script>
```

not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/colguess.js"></script>
```

When you reffer '/', it tends to say, looking for the file into the root directory. if files are in the same folder as in html, then no need to use '/'.

Comment: Thank you @Nalin. it's working now, that was dumb of me

Comment: Also note that the `type` attribute is optional in HTML5, so you can just write `<script src="colguess.js"></script>`

Comment: @Christoph yup!! after netscape2 it's not needed anymore !1 you are right. It's optional

Comment: @buggenerator It's Learnign phase brah !! :) . Mark this as a answer if it's helpfull !!

Comment: Also @NalinAggarwal could you tell me how to change the background `color` of the page before showing an alert message? (as found in the JS file)